# G and GHAT need to be same classification tree

Tags: matlab, tree, machine-learning, classification

Can someone help to solve and if possible explain my mistake.
I have a two numeric matrices for using it in classification tree

x: data matrix <2422x39 double>

y: column vector, class label for each instance <2422x1 double>

I'm doing:

```
t = classregtree(x, y, 'method','classification');
yPredicted = eval(t, x);
cm = confusionmat(y,yPredicted); // error
```

Error using ==> confusionmat at 52

G and GHAT need to be the same type.

Tree succesfully built. But I cannot get a confusion matrix for that example

I have read that post to write above code [Decision Tree in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960430/decision-tree-in-matlab)

If I use exactly same example from link, its working but when I use my own its not working.
Same steps I took for building regression tree ( t = classregtree(x, y) ) and no error in confusionmat() function.
Please explain what I'm doing incorrectly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me in your case, eval(t,x) returns cells of char type, while your x and y come with "double" type instead of "char".

The reason the code in [Decision Tree in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960430/decision-tree-in-matlab) works is because:

```
y = strcat(Origin,{});
```

returns y that is a cell with "char". Thus the argument G and GHAT have the same type.

So, select one that suits your problem:

---

**Approach A: convert yPredicted to numeric matrix**

Edit this line :

```
yPredicted = eval(t, x);
```

to :

```
yPredicted = str2num( cell2mat( eval(t, x) ) );
```

---

**Approach B: convert y to cell of char before calling confusionmat()**

```
 y = num2cell( num2str(y) )
```