# Coding a classification tree... how to store?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, dataset, binary-tree

I'm looking for a basic pseudo-code outline here.

My goal is to code a classification tree from scratch (I'm learning machine learning and want to get intuition).  But my training data is huge: 40000 examples and 1000 features.  Given that the upper bound for number of splits needed is 2<sup>40000</sup>, I'm lost as how to keep track of all these partitioned datasets.

Say I start with the full dataset and take one split.  Then I can save the 20000ish examples that fell on one side of the split into a dataset, and re-run the splitting algorithm to find the greedy split for that dataset.  Then say I keep doing this, splitting along the leftmost branches of the tree dozens of times.

When I'm satisfied with all my leftmost splits, then what?  How do I store up to 2<sup>40000</sup> separate subsets?  And how do I keep track of all the splits I've taken for when I'm classifying a test example?  It's the organization of the code that's not making sense to me.

Comment: It is not N=2^40000 splits, but 2^N=40000, which is N=log2(40000)<16. A tree 16 deep has more than 40000 leaf nodes. 2^40000 is a bogglingly large number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @natan for a detailed answer.

However, if I understand correctly, the main issue you are concern with is how to **efficiently** track each training sample as it propagates through the decision tree.

This can be done rather easily.

All you need is a vector of size `N=40000` with an entry per training sample. This vector will tell you where in the tree each sample is located. Lets call this vector `assoc`.

How to use this vector?

For my opinion, the most elegant way is to make `assoc` of type `uint32` and use the bits to encode the propagation of each training sample through the tree.

Each bit in `assoc(k)` represents certain depth of the tree, if this bit is set (1) it means that sample `k` went right, otherwise it means that sample `k` went left.

If you decide to go along this strategy, you'll find the following Matlab commands useful [`bitget`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html), [`bitset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitset.html), [`bitshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html) and some other bit-wise functions.

Lets consider the following tree

> ```
>        root
>       /    \
>      a      b
>            / \
>           c   d
> ```

So, for all examples that went to node *a* their `assoc` value is `00b` - since they went left at the root (corresponding to zero at the Least Significant Bit (LSB)).

All examples that went to leaf node *c*, their `assoc` value is `01b` - they went right at the root (LSB=1), then turned left (2nd bit=0).

Finally, all examples that went to leaf node *d*, their `assoc` value is `11b` - they took too right branches.

Now, How can you find all examples that went through node *b* ?

It's easy!

```
>> selNodeB = bitand( assoc, 1 );
```

All nodes that their LSB is `1` took the right turn at the root and pass through node *b*.

Answer (score 1):

If you think there is a way to store 2^40000 bits you haven't realize how big this number is, and you are wrong on about 10000 orders of magnitude.
Check Matlab's documentation of [classregtree](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/decision-trees.html;jsessionid=bdd9edf2457b92dad56e60d6fbd5).

I've copied from @Amro's detailed answer (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960430/decision-tree-in-matlab)) :

" Here are a few common parameters of the classification tree model:

- **x**: data matrix, rows are instances, cols are predicting attributes
- **y**: column vector, class label for each instance
- **categorical**: specify which attributes are discrete type (as opposed to continuous)
- **method**: whether to produce classification or regression tree (depend on the class type)
- **names**: gives names to the attributes
- **prune**: enable/disable reduced-error pruning
- **minparent/minleaf**: allows to specify min number of instances in a node if it is to be further split
- **nvartosample**: used in random trees (consider K randomly  chosen attributes at each node)
- **weights**: specify weighted instances
- **cost**: specify cost matrix (penalty of the various errors)
- **splitcriterion**: criterion used to select the best attribute at each split. I'm only familiar with the Gini index which is a variation of the Information Gain criterion.
- **priorprob**: explicitly specify prior class probabilities, instead of being calculated from the training data

A complete example to illustrate the process:

```
%# load data
load carsmall

%# construct predicting attributes and target class
vars = {'MPG' 'Cylinders' 'Horsepower' 'Model_Year'};
x = [MPG Cylinders Horsepower Model_Year];
y = strcat(Origin,{});

%# train classification decision tree
t = classregtree(x, y, 'method','classification', 'names',vars, ...
                'categorical', [2 4], 'prune','off');
view(t)

%# test
yPredicted = eval(t, x);
cm = confusionmat(y,yPredicted);           %# confusion matrix
N = sum(cm(:));
err = ( N-sum(diag(cm)) ) / N;             %# testing error

%# prune tree to avoid overfitting
tt = prune(t, 'level',2);
view(tt)

%# predict a new unseen instance
inst = [33 4 78 NaN];
prediction = eval(tt, inst)
```

[image: tree]