# How to use Decision Tree Classification Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-mining, decision-tree

I have data in form of rows and columns where rows represent a record and column represents its attributes.
I also have the labels (classes) for those records.

I know about decision trees concept and I would like to use matlab for classification of unseen records using decision trees.

How can this be done? I followed this link but its not giving me correct output-
[Decision Tree in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960430/decision-tree-in-matlab)

Essentially I want to construct a decision tree based on training data and then predict the labels of my testing data using that tree. Can someone please give me a good and working example for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following code to achieve it. And it is working correctly

```
function DecisionTreeClassifier(trainingFile, testingFile, labelsFile, outputFile)
training = csvread(trainingFile);
labels   = csvread(labelsFile);
testing  = csvread(testingFile);
tree = ClassificationTree.fit(training,labels)
prediction = predict(tree, testing)
csvwrite(outputFile, prediction)
```

Answer (score 1):

ClassificationTree.fit will be removed in a future release. Use fitctree instead.