# Information gain calculation

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I have this set with continued valued attribute `Temperature` and boolean valued attribute for `Play Tennis`:

```
Temperature:    40    48    60    72    80    90
Play Tennis:    No    No    Yes   Yes   Yes   No
```

And this is from a PPT that I was referencing: 
[image]

I understood each of these steps except the last one, that is the information gain calculation. I understood how the candidate threshold values of `54` and `85` are calculated too. But in the next slide, it says that the information gain for the `temp > 54` is chosen as the best one.

[image]

But based on my paper calculations on the example, am getting that the `temp > 85` should be chosen as it's gain value is higher!

My calculation:

[image]

Please excuse for the paper I used. I just do the calculations in any blank paper that I see in my room so as to avoid wastage of paper.

Based on this, I think am somewhere lost. Anyone have any ideas on how they mentioned that `temp > 54` is chosen as the best information gain?

Comment: Temp>54 has more conditions (55,56,57,..) than Temp>85 (only 86,87,...) so it has more freedom levels to choose (such as energy levels) so having  less available states mean less information to save since entrphy means useless statechanges or impurities(info=purity?)?

Comment: Thank you. So you are saying that if there's more samples then information gain would be higher?  Can you please provide a sample calculation too based on the above example? Because am still confused. I feel like am much dumb and not able to sleep(it's 2am here). Because I have been spending several hours on this information gain part

Comment: Are you sure, you got the concept of information gain? The idea is to compare the entropy before and after inserting an extra node. Your goal is to reduce the entropy (=uncertainty) by inserting splits. I would suggest having a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859554/what-is-entropy-and-information-gain