# Information gain vs minimizing entropy

Tags: math, decision-tree, entropy, information-gain

In what scenario is maximizing of information gain not equivalent to minimizing of entropy? The broader question is why do we need the concept of information gain? Is it not sufficient to work only with entropy to decide the next optimal attribute of a decision tree?

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859554/what-is-entropy-and-information-gain

Comment: Information_Gain = Entropy_before - Entropy_after

Comment: Isn't the Entropy_before constant? Doesn't that mean that we should only look to minimize Entropy_after?

Comment: Yes. Maximizing the information_Gain and minimizing the Entropy_after is the same thing.

Comment: I agree - I cannot see the difference either. But there might be a difference and sklearn even scales the gain witht the fraction of observation in each node https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html which, in my eyes, is just multiplying with a constant, which should make no difference what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Maximizing the IG (also known as Mutual Information) tends to provide the same result as minimizing the entropy.

Basically, if you minimize the entropy you're forcing Information Gain to be maximum.