# How to calculate the information gain of a continuous feature

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, feature-extraction, entropy, information-extraction

I'm having problem in in finding the right parameters for the information gain, if I don't have any discrete values and thus I first need to discretize these points into intervals.

**What I have**:

I'm doing image processing, where my features have a possible range 0-255. With some training data I can define some intervals (which only define "is object or is *not* object"). If `goods` are the number of intervals for for a matching point and `bads` is labeled for its environment. I'll calculate it this way with

[image: formula]

information gain for this case:

[image: formula]

where

[image: formula]

**Results and idea**:

For some reason I end up with a **negative** IG which is quiet nonsense but I don't see the error. Another idea was instead of counting the *object-matching* intervals for`good`, count the samples in `good` that fit into any good-interval.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what you have there as before and after (or P and Q) distributions.

Have you changed anything to go from one situation to another? It's unclear.

Look at [What is "entropy and information gain"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859554/what-is-entropy-and-information-gain)

It seems good+bad represent the whole distribution.

So you need to have something change to go from one (good, bad) to another (good, bad).

Then you apply the formula correctly - or follow the example

Your formula seems to be messed up.

Comment: well if I hadn't seen stuff like this I wouldn't have a solution either. The thing is I don't see where I went wrong

Comment: I think you are trying to trainan image recognition/processing sytem right? The two situations I'm referring to are: you trained your system and got performance A: good=X, bad=Y, then trained again and got B: good=Z, bad=W. I you can verify you have these two situations (A, B) to compare we can go further

Comment: to put a close ito it: IG=[Entropy(X/(X+Y))+Entropy(Y/(X+Y))]-[Entropy(Z/(Z+W))+Entropy(W/(Z+W))] - you cant get info gain with only one run of the experiment - can you get moving by standing still??

Comment: **Solution**: If anyone has a similiar problem. I was missing out to wander around the whole range from 0 - 255 to find the best split position for the information gain to a particular feature.