# Decision Tree - Can the Entropy of a Node be Zero?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

The formula for information gain is give by,

```
Information Gain = entropy(parent) – [average entropy(children)]
```

Can the entropy be zero, which means in some case:

```
entropy(parent) == [average entropy(children)]
```

Comment: hmmm..., let me search for it, but just imagine an artificial case where all examples belong to the same class

Comment: yeah, check this out, very well explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859554/what-is-entropy-and-information-gain?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Guiem haha i just fount that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"When `H(S) = 0`, the set S is perfectly classified (i.e. all elements in S are of the same class)." -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm

`H(S)` = entropy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Guiem gave the correct answer, which is that the entropy is zero when all elements of a set belong to the same class. But with regard to your question, there are two additional points worth noting:

First, when implementing a decision tree, if `entropy(parent)` is zero, there is no reason to compute the Information Gain of `children`, since the data are already perfectly classified (i.e., you are at a leaf node of the tree).

Second, the case of `entropy(parent) == [average entropy(children)]` doesn't necessarily only occur when the entropy of `parent` is zero. It can also occur when `parent` has nonzero entropy (i.e., the Information Gain from splitting on `children` is zero), which suggests that splitting on `children` will not improve classification performance.