# What feature selection algorithm would I use to find out which feature impacts each class the most?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, feature-selection

I am currently experimenting with a data set,using supervised learning with 10 features and 3 classes, but a question arose that is, what feature selection algorithm would I use to find out which feature impacts which class the most, or which combination of features will result in what class.

For Example Take a data set of Hours Slept and Hours studied which may result in a pass or a fail.

[image]

I want to know How does Hours Studies impact the pass class and how it impacts the fail class and the same for Hours Slept how does it impact pass or fail.

What Feature selection method will tell me that Hours Slept has x impact on Fail and y on Pass, and the same for Hours studied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to observe how the entropy of the class label distribution changes after you partition the class values according to attribute values for a given attribute. The attribute that gives the largest entropy reduction is the "best" one. (This works for discrete attributes only; you'll have to discretize the attributes in order to use this method; e.g. say convert `hoursSlept>7` to `sleptAlot`; convert `5 <=hoursSlept<=7` to `sleptEnough`; and `hoursSlept<5` to `sleepDeprived`.)

The entropy `H` of a discrete distribution `(p1,p2,...,pk)` is defined as

```
H = -p1*log_2 p1 - p2*log_2 p2 - ... - pk*log_2 pk
```

and it measures, roughly speaking, the impurity of the distribution. The less you can tell about the outcome apriori the higher the entropy; the more you can tell about the outcome apriori the smalles the entropy. In fact, the distribution `pi=1/k` for all `i` (where all outcomes are equally likely) has the highest possible entropy (value `log_2 k`); and distributions where `pi=1` for some `i` have the lowest possible entropy (value `0`).

Define `pi=ni/n` where `n` is the number of examples and `ni` is the number of examples with `i`-th class value. This induces a discrete distribution `(p1,p2,...,pk)` where `k` is the number of class values.

For an attribute `A` with possible values `a1,a2,...,ar` define `Si` to be the set of those examples whose value of the attribute `A` equals `ai`. Each of the sets `Si` induces a discrete distribution (defined in the same way as before). Let `|Si|` be the number of examples in the set `Si`. Denote the corresponding entropy by `H(Si)`.

Now compute

```
Gain(A) = H - |S1|/n * H(S1) - ... - |Sr|/n * H(Sr)
```

and pick the attribute that maximizes `Gain(A)`. The intuition is that the attribute that maximizes this difference partitions the examples so that in most `Si`'s the examples have similar labels (i.e. entropy is low).

Intuitively the value of `Gain(A)` tells you how informative is the attribute `A` about the class labels.

For your reference, this is widely used in decision-tree learning, and the measure is referred to as information gain. See, for example, [these slides](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shapiro/EE596/notes/InfoGain.pdf); this [explanation on Math.SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1859910/2483038) is really great (although it's in the context of decision-tree learning).

Comment: Lovely,Thanks Blazs I think I understand now, Really detailed, It led me to another question tho. What do I use to get the impact on a specific attribute values on the class Eg lets say we discretized the attributes as you mentioned hours slept would be the attribute and sleptAlot would be the attribute value I am interested in knowing how it impacts pass or fail. Thanks!!!

Comment: So the question is how do the individual attribute values affect the class? You could quantify this by computing `H(S_sleptAlot)` and then comparing it to `H` (e.g. take the difference). If you want to know how the attribute value affects the actual class values, you can look at the distribution itself.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :-)